# How to automate a pdf generation including some js charts library?

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, charts

what I'm trying to do is to generate, lets say a word document or even a PDF, where i can place charts from any js Charts library. I'm actually implementing the library in some other websites, but I want to have the same charts in my documents.

What i have tried so far is using the C# webclient with no results, since it does not run javascript.
In other words how would you do to automatically have your js charts like amcharts or highcharts into a pdf or word document?

Comment: This is one of the "can do, but should I do?" cases. ChartJS is meant for front-end. I bet you can find other libraries specific to PDF.

Comment: Got it, so you mean there is no way to take advantage of having a chartjs library to be copied and pasted into a pdf? Something like using phantom JS? cause I tried with no luck

Comment: I don't see an advantage of using a library outside the scope it was meant to be used. Your task is very common (add charts to PDFs). I am 100% sure there are many libraries out there that can do that for you. It's not worth it to force the use of a library outside it's directive.

Comment: Well actually I just intended to have the same charts into these generated docs.
but thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't clearly understand whether you want to do that server side or client side to generate the pdf files with charts, but I [did](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autocosts) exactly that on the client side (browser), using chartsJs for the charts and pdfmake for the pdf generation. The library pdfmake allows you to add base64 images to the pdf and chartJs has ways to convert the charts to base64 images.

Therefore, if you want/may do it client side (or front-end)

- you need [pdfmake](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmake) for the generation of pdf
- you need [chartJs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chart.js?activeTab=readme), for the charts (contrary to Google charts, this works offline and you need no extra api, certificates or anything like that)
- you then convert the charts to base64 images and then add them to the pdf template before generating the pdf.

You can try on the [website I developed on the playground](https://autocosts.info/xx), advance to the last steps and then click "download pdf", and you'll see charts therein.

Comment: seems like this is going to help a lot here, thank you!

Comment: @LuisGPalomares btw, the code I developed is open source, the front-end of the site is [here](https://github.com/jfoclpf/autocosts/tree/master/src/client), where you'll find the charts and pdf modules, hope that helps.